# Is it true that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Is it true that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0$? I intuitively think this is true, but really no idea to prove it. Can you give me hints?

Comment: **Hint**: Go back to the definition of limits. The same $\delta$ should work in either of the cases. This becomes obvious when you picture the geometric version of the definition :)

Comment: @Sawarnik Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Start:** Let $\epsilon > 0$, then by [definition of the limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28mathematics%29#Limit_of_a_function) $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0,$$ follows that there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x$ in the domain of $f$ with $0<|x-a|< \delta,$ we have
$$|f(x)|=|f(x)-0|< \epsilon$$

Now, write the definition of $\lim_{x \to a}|f(x)| = 0$ to conclude.